# Passing php variable to template in MyBB forum

Tags: php, templates, eval, mybb

I've a **problem** with my [MyBB forum](http://hardforo.com) **passing php variables to MyBB template**, I want I'cant pass $width y $height

I can effectively use PHP in templates using a plugin so this should work:

```
<div style="float:right; display:inline-block; width: <?php echo $width; ?>px; height: <?php echo $height; ?>px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" >
```

But not! echo works but print nothing!

From controller-side I've this:

```
$height = 240;
$width = 120;
// ...
eval("\$width = \"\$width\";");
eval("\$height = \"\$height\";");
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I've been using {$height} and {$width} with no-difference

Comment: I'm not even sure what you are trying to accomplish with `eval` there?

Comment: DarkBee me too! **I'm trying to pass some variables from controller to the template** to use them there but I guess It's accomplish with eval() although I've not idea how.

Answer (score 0):

This is because MyBB requires you to make the variable global to make it visible to the template. As far as I know, there is no other way to pass it along.

Add the following at the top of the function where you define the variables:

```
global $width, $height;
```

This makes them accessible outside of the function scope. See [Variable Scope in the PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information on how this works.

You should also double check to make sure that the hook is run before the template is passed to `eval()`.